# Puppet: process local template

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet, I am facing one issue with the same.

How can I use the erb template on the clients node and process them through puppet class, I know the templates need to be on the puppet master but my erb templates are on client node. Is there any way to accomplish this?

One more issue, can I execute any commmand on client node(again not on puppet master) through puppet??

Comment: Please raise only one issue per Question. Open another one if you need guidance on multiple problems.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are evaluated during catalog compilation. The master sends this catalog to the node.  I suspect you want to have node-specific settings applied, which you can use with [facter](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/) and [custom facts](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.4/custom_facts.html).